# Make local web app accessable by http://LocalComputer/WebsiteName on IIS

Tags: http, url, iis, binding, web

I am trying to make web app accessible by http://LocalComputer/WebsiteName on IIS.

I am able to access it by http://computername:portnumber/

So what does my binding need to be and do I need a static ip?

Any help or redirection to appropriate resources will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Is IIS setup on default port 80? If your document root is setup to website, you should be able to access it via http://computername/. If this is a local setup, and assuming your DNS is setup and working on the router, wont need a static IP although doubtful IP will ever change.

Comment: it is on port 90 the reason I ask is so I can run multiple website without typing in port number but url

Comment: Browser will always try port 80 if http and port 443 if https, no way to change that. If server is running on a different port, will have to type in port. You can assign your local computer multiple private IPs on the same subnet and bind different sites to each IP and have different hostname, you can set IP to hostname in your hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

http://LocalComputer/WebsiteName this can be done locally without a static IP.

In order to make it publically over http you would need below things.

1) Registered domain name
2) Registered name servers
3) DNS zone created for the domain either with registrar or on the server

You can either host this website by renting a Windows VPS or a server and with the help of third party control panels like Plesk or Hosting controller.

OR

You can purchase a shared web hosting space from a windows hosting provider and upload your pages to make the contents accessible publically.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to set multiple domains in your hosts file

domain1 192.168.0.10
domain2 192.168.0.10
...

Set IIS to bind and hosts multiple domain on the same IP. Then you can access each site locally by going to http://domain1 or http://domain2 etc...